# SQL statement to check if ANY value in table 1 does have a value when match with another value in table 2 and, if so, do not return

Tags: sql, duplicates, teradata, toad

I am using SQL through Toad

So I have data where I am trying to see if an internal item number exists in table 1 and does not exist in table 2 for the same mfg number. This would be really easy if I had clean data but I don't and I can't change it so I have duplicate items in table 2 where some have an item number and some don't.

Here is what I need:

Find a mfg number that has an internal item number in table 1 and check to see if for the same mfg number it has an internal item number in any of the duplicate records on table 2. Do not return anything if any record has an item number in table 2.

Example data:

Table 1:

Mfg Number | Item number

1. 1 | 123
2. 2 | 456
3. 3 | 789

Table 2:

Mfg Number | Item number

1. 1 | 123
2. 1 | 123
3. 1 | NULL
4. 2 | NULL
5. 2 | NULL
6. 2 | NULL
7. 3 | 789
8. 3 | 789
9. 3 | 789

This is what I tried:

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table 1
INNER JOIN Table 2 ON Mfg Number = Mfg Number
WHERE table 1 item number IS NOT NULL
AND table 2 item number IS NULL

This produced false data because it returns both item 1 and item 2. Even though item 1 does have an item number in some of the records, I am only seeing the one where it is null.

What I would want to see is only item 2 because ALL of the item number fields for that item are null.

Not sure if this is possible but if it is I figured this would be the place to find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See if this gets you what you're after.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tblTable1;
CREATE TABLE #tblTable1(
     MfgNumber nvarchar(100)
    ,ItemNumber nvarchar(100)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tblTable2;
CREATE TABLE #tblTable2(
     MfgNumber nvarchar(100)
    ,ItemNumber nvarchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO #tblTable1(MfgNumber, ItemNumber)
VALUES(1, 123)
    ,(2, 456)
    ,(3,789);

INSERT INTO #tblTable2(MfgNumber, ItemNumber)
VALUES (1, 123)
    ,(1, 123)
    ,(1, NULL)
    ,(2, NULL)
    ,(2, NULL)
    ,(2, NULL)
    ,(3, 789)
    ,(3, 789)
    ,(3, 789)

SELECT * FROM #tblTable1
SELECT * FROM #tblTable2

SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM #tblTable1 a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
                FROM #tblTable2 b
                WHERE a.MfgNumber = b.MfgNumber
                    AND a.Itemnumber = b.Itemnumber)
```

Comment: This one is still pulling in the case where it is null under one of the rows on item 1

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  Added the test setup.

Answer (score 0):

So you want all columns from Table1 where all rows in Table2 with that Mfg_Number have NULL Item_Number?

```
SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Mfg_Number FROM Table2
  GROUP BY Mfg_Number 
  HAVING MAX(Item_Number) IS NULL
  ) AS AllNull
 ON Table1.Mfg_Number = AllNull.Mfg_Number
WHERE Table1.Mfg_Number IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: The WHERE clause is not strictly necessary - NULL Mfg_Number would be implicitly excluded by the test for equality in the ON clause. I just included it for clarity.

Comment: I think this one might work, I have nearly 1 million items after all the duplicates that it has to go through and I haven't had time to let it sit and go through the query (the work laptop is slow) I will let you know if I end up being able to run this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, I used a subquery to pull all the item numbers from table 2 (disconnecting them from the mfg numbers) and then matched the results against the item numbers in table 1. If it came back as null that means the item number does not exist in table 2 at all. Since the item numbers are unique and non-repeating, this works.

[image: SQL Statement solution]

Comment: If this returns the expected result you better go with NOT EXISTS from @CSharp821 Just remove the `a.MfgNumber = b.MfgNumber`